# easy_install pywebkitgtk error: Couldn't find a setup script

Tags: python, easy-install

I try to install turpial(a twitter client) from source code in slax and it require pywebkitgtk to work.But I got error while using easy_install to install it.

The console output:

```
root@slax:~# easy_install pywebkitgtk
Searching for pywebkitgtk
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/pywebkitgtk/
Reading http://code.google.com/p/pywebkitgtk/
Reading http://code.google.com/p/pywebkitgtk/downloads/list
Best match: pywebkitgtk 1.1.8
Downloading https://pywebkitgtk.googlecode.com/files/pywebkitgtk-1.1.8.tar.gz
Processing pywebkitgtk-1.1.8.tar.gz
error: Couldn't find a setup script in /tmp/easy_install-M9rve1/pywebkitgtk-1.1.8.tar.gz
```

Then,I downloaded this package and found really no setup script in it.

Is there anyone successfully installed pywebkitgtk through easy_install?

Thanks!!!